Jensen's proof that $\diamondsuit$ holds at subtle cardinals
At the end of these notes by Ronald Jensen (which I found from this question) there is a proof that $\diamondsuit_\kappa$ (diamond principle) holds if $\kappa$ is a subtle cardinal.

By induction on $\alpha \lt \kappa$ define $\langle S_\alpha, C_\alpha \rangle$ s(uch) t(hat) $S_\alpha \subset \alpha$, $C_\alpha$ is closed, unbounded in $\alpha$ and $\forall \gamma \in C_\alpha S_\gamma \neq \gamma \cap S_\alpha$ if possible.


Claim If $S \subset \kappa$, then $\{\alpha \lt \kappa | S \cap = S_\alpha\}$ is Mahlo [stationary]. Suppose not. Then there is a pair $\langle S, C \rangle$ s(uch) t(hat) $S \subset \kappa$, $C$ is closed, unbounded in $\kappa$ and $\forall \alpha \in C$ $S_\alpha \neq \alpha \cap S$


Let $C^*$ be the set of limit p(oin)ts of $C$. Then $\alpha \in C^* \implies \forall \gamma \in C^*$ $S_\gamma \neq \gamma \cap S_\alpha$.


By the subtlety of $\kappa$, however, there are $\alpha, \beta \in C^*$ s(uch) t(hat) $\alpha \lt \beta$, $C_\alpha = \alpha \cap C_\beta$, $S_\alpha = \alpha \cap S_\beta$. Hence $\alpha \in C_\beta \wedge S_\alpha = \alpha \cap S_\beta$.


Contradiction!

I don't understand why the claim in the second paragraph follows from the other paragraphs, as they don't mention $S$.

The "Suppose not" in the second paragraph is the reason for the fact in the third paragraph (and is thus what leads to the desired contradiction).
The point is that the definition of $\langle S_\alpha,C_\alpha\rangle$ says to make $S_\gamma$ disagree with previous $S_\alpha$'s if possible. $S$ and $C$ guarantee that this will actually be possible, because initial segments of $S$ and $C$ serve as witnesses of the possibility at every stage in $C'$.

I don't see why initial segments of $S$ would witness the contradiction on whether the $S_\alpha$ can disagree with each other. The initial segments of $S$ agree because they are initial segments!

@ArvidSamuelsson At any stage $\alpha$ of the construction of the $S_\alpha$'s and $C_\alpha$'s, you're looking for a subset of $\alpha$ that disagrees with the previously chosen $S_\beta$'s for a club (in $\alpha$) set of $\beta$'s. $S\cap\alpha$ is such a set, the relevant club being $C\cap\alpha$, because of the assumption that $S$ disagrees with $S_\beta$ for all $\beta\in C$.

It might be useful to point out a curious aspect of this argument. The choice of $S$ and $C$ ensures a lot of disagreement between $S\cap\beta$ and $S_\beta$. That disagreement ensures that the "if possible" clause is satisfied at every stage $\alpha\in C'$. So at such a stage $\alpha$, the set $S\cap\alpha$ was a candidate to be the next term $S_\alpha$ to be chosen. But in fact, a different candidate won, since the actual $S_\alpha$ is not equal to $S\cap\alpha$.

But why does a contradiction follow from the assumption that $S_\alpha = S \cap \alpha$ and $S_\beta$ is undefined for $\beta \gt \alpha$?

I don't understand "$S_\beta$ is undefined for  $\beta>\alpha$"; the first paragraph of the proof defines $S_\beta$ for all $\beta<\kappa$.  The contradiction arises (approximately) because, on the one hand, the inductive definition of the $S_\alpha$'s ensures that they disagree with each other while, on the other hand, $\kappa$ being subtle ensures that some of them have to agree. Here "approximately" refers to the fact that these agreements & disagreements hold only for ordinals in $C$ or $C'$ or some $C_\alpha$, and one has to make sure they all fit together correctly.

I think I misunderstood what was meant by "if possible". I assumed that the sequence of  $S_\alpha$ must disagree, and that it is undefined if there is no sequence that satisfies that condition. But the proof makes sense if they are allowed to agree if unavoidable.
